# How do I remove folder name from My website URL address?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, amazon-web-services

[Here's the link to our website.](http://www.edu4sure.com/)
Now the trouble is `/edu4sure` appears after the main URL whenever someone opens the website and I want to change this.

`www.edu4sure.com/edu4sure`

to

`www.edu4sure.com/`

We are using Codeigniter as the PHP framework,
Here's my index.php in the htdocs folder:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
    $uri = 'https://';
} else {
    $uri = 'http://';
}
$uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
header('Location: '.$uri.'/edu4sure');
exit;
?>
```

Something is wrong with the XAMPP installation :-(

Here's the htacess from the edu4sure folder or the directory:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|      (.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Here's the htaccess from application folder of my website

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

We have our website server on amazon web services(aws) although we have bought the domain from godaddy. I have installed xamp on aws like a local machine and have placed our website in the htdocs folder as we normally do.
Please help. An example would be appreciated.
Here's a link to the snap of record set

```
https://1drv.ms/i/s!AgEZGcb3iEuwpDIx-355sXVwJ_tY
```

Comment: Why do you have this line of code in index.php ? header('Location: '.$uri.'/edu4sure');

Comment: Hello, I have no clue its been a while since we published out website.

Comment: Do you have a header.php file in the file system and what is its location

Comment: Yes i do.
Its inside layout folder in the view directory.

Comment: Add this to hatches file RewriteRule (.*) http://www.edu4sure.com/$1 [R=301,L] and see if it works

Comment: Thanks for the help, but which htaccess exactly?

Comment: No did not help instead redirected to following url 
http://www.edu4sure.com/C:/xampp/htdocs/edu4sure/edu4sure.com/

Comment: Add this above that rule I told you and see Options +FollowSymLinks

Comment: No did not help. Infact now the site is not opening at all even with the previous settings

Comment: Okay its back to normal now, but edu4sure after the site name still exists.

Comment: Check my answer below. Keep the htaccess the same it was before

Comment: What do i exactly need to add? 
i added this to my htaccess in the root directory
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule (.*) edu4sure.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Hey i tried it again, maybe missed something last time.
Now it says server error

Comment: Did you try my answer below?

Comment: Yes, worked. 
But
/edu4sure is still there in url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by removing the folder name from base_url in the config file in the config directory of Codeigniter. Then i added a new virtual host value in the httpd-vhosts file inside

```
c:\xammp\apache\conf\extra

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/edu4sure"
ServerName http://edu4sure.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Server Name is the name that you want to redirect to and DocumentRoot is the path to your project root.

Also added following entry in the end of host file inside

127.0.0.1       http://edu4sure.com

Worked like a charm after this.

Comment: Yup this was the file I asked you yesterday  good you fixed it.

Comment: Hahaha You should've specified, either way its working now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is the Apache Configuration file you made change right?

Comment: its the vhos apace file.